# Brake clicking sound in Infiniti Q50S

Tags: brakes, troubleshooting, infiniti

I have a 2016 Infiniti Q50S and since almost a year upon braking I hear and feel something clicking inside the brakes.

The Infiniti guys have attempted to diagnose the problem but have never been able to get to the bottom of it. The brake operation seems fine. However I would love to know the reason behind those clicks. What if they turn into a more serious problem.

Anyone else has a similar undiagnosable clicking complaint in Q50S?

Comment: Most likely the pads shifting on braking... if they are a little small as can happen in the manufacturing process and the caliper fractionally large then there may be more play than normal. Try a new set of pads...